# Selecting record from one table and insert it into different table with different structure avoiding duplicates

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with different structure, say `property_bid` and `sc_property_queries`.

`sc_property_queries` holds value from `property_bid` as well as another table. And there is a field called `query_method` in a destination table which tells from which table the rows came from. The field `raw_id` holds the ID from the source tables. What I want to do is , selecting from the `property_bid` table and insert it into `sc_property_queries`, but with new items only, i.e. avoiding the duplicates based on `raw_id` and `query_method`. Below is my MySQL code which doesn't seem to work

```
INSERT INTO sc_property_queries (
  `property_id`,
  `raw_id`, `query_method`,
  `contact_fullname`,
  `contact_address`,
  `contact_email`,
  `contact_phone`,
  `contact_date`,
  `entry_date`,
  `title`,
  `query_status`,
  `remarks`,
  `description`
) 
SELECT 
 t1.property_id,
  t1.id,
  'web-bids',
  t1.fullname,
  'n/a',
  t1.email,
  t1.phone,
  t1.on_date,
  NOW(),
  'n/a',
  '1',
  'n/a',
  t1.comment 
FROM
  property_bid t1 
  LEFT JOIN sc_property_queries t2 
    ON (t1.id = t2.raw_id) 
WHERE  t2.query_method='web-bids' AND t2.raw_id IS NULL;
```

This query should return the all the rows from `property_bid` that doesnot exist in sc_property_queries. But it is not doing anything. Can anybody shed light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WHERE t2.raw_id IS NULL` restricts your resultset to only those records that do not exist in `t2`; therefore `t2.*` are all `NULL`.  Hence this criterion cannot be true simultaneously with the other criterion `WHERE t2.query_method='web-bids'`.

Perhaps you meant to include that criterion in the join:

```
FROM
  property_bid t1 
  LEFT JOIN sc_property_queries t2 
    ON (t1.id = t2.raw_id AND t2.query_method='web-bids')
WHERE t2.raw_id IS NULL
```

Comment: if I remove `t2.query_method='web-bids'`, it works but this will avoid inserting rows from another table `property_comments` because of same id conflict

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JOIN just use NOT IN:

```
FROM
  property_bid t1 
  where 
   t1.id not in (select t2.raw_id from sc_property_queries t2 where t2.query_method='web-bids')
```